# Select objects programatically without triggering SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there some way to call `viewer.select([...])` from inside selection event listener callback without triggering the `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`?

The following code currently results in an infinite loop, cause `viewer.select(...)` triggers the `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`. The `SetTimeout(...)` call is in place only to prevent call stack overflow.

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, () => {
    setTimeout(
        () =>
            viewer.select(
                [
                    ...new Set([
                        ...itemsThatShouldRemainSelected,
                        ...viewer.getSelection(),
                    ]),
                ],
                undefined,
                -1,
            ),
        100,
    );
    console.log('SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to stop triggering `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`. Why do you want to change the selected object after `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` gets fired? That sounds a bit weird.

Comment: It is indeed a bit weird. I've got selected items in the viewer that need to keep being selected, hence `itemsThatShouldRemainSelected`. I've simply changed `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` to `click` for now and removed the `SetTimeout`, etc. Thank you for taking a look at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood! Thanks for sharing the use case.

After diagnosing into viewer, I found the below, but we still need something to store pre-selected dbIds somewhere.

To prevent the `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` getting triggered, we can use `model.selector.setSelection( dbIds, selectionType )` to bypass the event trigger.

```js
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];

// Select
model.selector.setSelection( dbIds, selectionType ); //!<<< selectionType is optional.

// clear selections
model.selector.clearSelection();
```

**Note.** The functions above are internal functions used in [Viewer3D#select](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#select-dbids-model-selectiontype), [Viewer3D#clearSelection](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#clearselection), which might be changed someday in the future. So, please use them at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Bellow is what I've ended up using in order to keep the previously selected items selected. I's not the kind of solution that I'd like as I'd still like to have a more programmatic control over the `viewer.select()` call but anyway.

`items: Item[]` is something that I track using a sort of client side state management and for that reason I have these `selectedInViewer` and `itemDbId` properties. The `[...new Set .....])` kind of thing is just how to make a union in modern JS.

```js
...
    public preventItemsDeselection(
        viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D,
        items: Item[],
    ) {
        viewer.canvas.onclick = () => {
            viewer.select([
                ...new Set([
                    ...items.filter(i => i.selectedInViewer).map(i => i.itemDbId),
                    ...viewer.getSelection(),
                ]),
            ]);
        };
    }
...
```

In order to call the above method one could do the following, where items have `selectedInViewer` and `itemDbId` properties.

```js
instance.preventItemsDeselection(viewer, items);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a case for this as well.

- We want to have predefined selection sets. e.g select all doors, select the front door...
- We want users to be able to select from these sets and have them highlight in the table via the `viewer.select()` function while still also allowing selection via the viewer itself
- Each time a new object in the viewer is highlighted we want to fetch some additional information stored in an external db
- TRICKY PART: Because of how our application works, when going from a selection set we must first look up the matching viewerIds/dbIds before adding them to the selected viewer items form highlighting via `viewer.select()`. At the same time, items selected directly via the viewer need to then use the viewerIds/dbIds to look up the related data (the reverse operation). This is handled via the `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` handler.
- The problem is that calling the `viewer.select()` function always triggers the `SELECTION_CHANGE_EVENT`. Therefore, we end up having to do a lot more extra logic to determine the source of the triggered event. What would be nice is a way to called `viewer.select()` while preventing the `SELECTION_CHANGE_EVENT`. Is anything like this possible?

kind regards